# Programmatically click link in iframe with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Here's my html/javascript. Below there are two if statements that I've tried. I used indexof to get the text between the `<a></a>` tags. Also tried `href ==` to use the `href=` contents. Both do not work.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>pb</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function call() {
        alert("Called!");
        var allAnc = document.getElementById("d").contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < allAnc.length; i++) {
            if (allAnc[i].href.indexOf("Flag") > 0) {
                alert("Found link by indexof, Trying to click!");
                (allAnc[i]).click();
                break;
            }
            if (allAnc[i].href == "javascript:flag.closeit()") {
                alert("Found link by href, Trying to click!");
                (allAnc[i]).click();
                break;
            }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="call()" value="button" />
    <iframe id="d" src="sourceurl.html" width="100%" height=700"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the link inside the iframe I am trying to click:

```html
<a style="text-align: left;" href="javascript:flag.closeit()" title="Flag">Flag</a>
```

Comment: Is the iframe from the same domain or a different domain?

Comment: @user2668641 you can't read the content of another domain.

Comment: Please upvote and/or accept the answers if they helped you. If they didn't help you, please ask for more information or clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, you are loading the content of different domain into you iframe, so you just can't read the content of that domain due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo of the issue, code mostly copied & pasted from your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/colllin/G2BDb/

And the inner iframe code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/colllin/wc8Up/

As you can see in the console when you click the button,

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/#Flag' in a frame because
    it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

So it looks like if you have control over **the page that the iframe is linking to**, you could set `X-Frame-Options` header on that page to be specify an `ALLOW-FROM` uri ([from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)):

```
ALLOW-FROM uri
  The page can only be displayed in a frame on the specified origin.
```

---

Alternatively if you have control over the original iframe source (which I assume you do, otherwise it's impossible to even access the contents, let alone click a link), you could add the `target="_top"` attribute to the link before clicking it.  **This would cause the linked page to replace your top-level page in the window.**

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/colllin/G2BDb/2/