# Click a link inside an iframe programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

There is a remote page. The page contains just 1 a href link in it. I iframe the page, and want to click the link programatically. I have tried this without any luck

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/"></iframe>

<script>
window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName('a').click();
</script>
```

Is there anyway to do that ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193078/programatically-click-link-in-iframe-with-javascript

Comment: Because of the Same Origin Policy, this is not possible. You can send events back and forth from parent to iframe though. [Check this out](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage)

Comment: Really ? So how do others submit forms within an iframe using     document.forms[0].submit(); ?